# FATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres [SQL State=28P01]

Tags: postgresql

So I'm using postgresql 13 and SQL Workbench on Windows 10 for the first time. I'm trying to connect the database to the server to no avail. I keep getting this error message: FATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres [SQL State=28P01]. From Stack Overflow and other documentation, I'm able to gather things about older versions of postgres or how to address this issue in Ubuntu and/or from the command line. But I have yet to find a remedy that fits my specific circumstance. Anyone have tips on how I can fix this or even better search terms that point towards a more precise solution? Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Generally this means you have supplied the wrong password for the user.

Comment: Please post the complete message from the server's log file.  The message give to the unauthenticated client is intentionally vague.